# Is every NP-Easy problem also in NP problems?

Tags: algorithm

May be I am not understanding this right but I am looking for a diagram that shows how NP-Easy and NP problem sets are related. Are all NP-Easy problems in NP?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:P_np_np-complete_np-hard.svg

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I was looking for something that shows NP-Easy's relationship to NP.

Comment: You are looking for answer in the wrong place. This is StackOverflow, to get more answers, go to [StackExchange's site focused on Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/), having [similar questions like this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27032/np-vs-np-complete).

Answer (score 2):

Well yes they are in a colloquial sense. NP-Easy problems are function problems, i.e. the goal is compute an output based on an input, where as NP problems are decisions problems, i.e. the goal is to compute a boolean result (yes or no) based on an input. NP-Easy is just the equivalent of NP for function problems instead of decision problems.

In other words, NP-Easy and NP problems are computationally as hard, but they are two different, not comparable classes of problems because NP problems are decision problems and NP-Easy problems are function problems.

Answer (score 0):

In NP only the checking part needs to be polynomial time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336374/np-complete-problems hence np-easy is in np.